# Unable to Import .Rdata to RMarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I use Windows and try to read .Rdata file to RMarkdown using rio's import function. It keeps giving me errors. This works just fine when I'm using R code in the same folder.

So here is the code in the first RMarkdown code chunk

```
{r setup, include = FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(tidyverse) 
library(rio) 

df_clean <- import("data/df_clean.rdata")

Error in import("data/df_clean.rdata") : No such file
```

Is there a different between using R Code or RMarkdown? This also works fine when I type it in the R console, but doesn't work in the R Code chunk in the RMarkdown.

When I check in the working directory, the file is there

```
> getwd()
[1] "C:/Users/Project/Project A"

> list.files()
[1] "code"                                                      "data"                                                     
[3] "documentation"                                             "output"   

> list.files("data")
[1] "archive"                         "df_clean.rdata"                  "df_unique.rdata"
```

I'm new to R and just start coding this year. I hope I can do my EDA in RMarkdown to become more organized. Kindly help me with the question format if I did not posted it correctly.

Comment: Where is your markdown file located? In RStudio...Tools...Global Options...RMarkdown there is an option to "Evaluate chunks in directory" that is set to "document" by default so paths should be relative to the markdown document.

Comment: The markdown file is in the "code" folder.  What does it means when the default is "document"? Should I check it to "current'?

Comment: You can either change the RStudio setting or you can change the relative path used to point to the rdata file to be relative to the markdown file itself.

Comment: Ok, I finally understand it. I haven't read this book but I guess this is what you are trying to explain: 
[link](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/working-directory.html)
"By default, the working directory for R code chunks is the directory that contains the Rmd document." 

When I put the markdown file in the main file, "Project A", it has no problem importing the dataset as it can takes from "Project A/data". If I want to change the path relative to the markdown file, I can follow the step in the book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you unsure of the file path of the RData to import, use this to make Selection manually first..

```
df_clean <- import(file.choose())
```

or you can also get the full path of your RData stored in variable by doing:

```
RData_path <- file.choose()
df_clean <- import(RData_path)
```